# App freeze and then crashes on splash screen

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-4

I have an iPhone App published for a while, developed under the SDK3, and everything works great. Some weeks ago, when Apple released the SDK4 I made some changes to my app to support multitasking (it plays audio in the background).

In my simulator and my device (iPhone 3GS iOS4) the app runs great, there is no problem at all. But, now when I submit the update, a lot of users are contacting me because they say that the app freezes on the splash screen and after waiting about 40-60 seconds, it crashes.

By asking to the users, I have determinate that the problem is only in those devices that haves iOS4 (iPhone 3Gs and 4G).

I tested the app over and over in my simulator and my device but it never happens to me!! Some one have any idea or information about this?

I will really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe they're holding it wrong. ;-)

Comment: If You want to understand what the problem, ask users to send you Crash Reports for your application.

2David: great comment :))

Comment: Aren't Crash Reports available in iTunesConnect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After search for the crashes, and try over and over, I can't reproduce the bug on 
my devices. So, I decide to start reading at the Apple Developer Forums and I 
found a thread where my suspicions are affirmed: this problem is caused by an internal
iOS4 bug.

"There's a bug in the App Store's code signing process. Talk to DTS: they can 
help you with the workaround. Mention rdar://7909951."

"...but it should be the cause of nearly all "failed to launch in time" inside 
libobjc:_mapStrHash..." (This appears in some of my app crashes)

Here is the link to the post: [failed to launch in time in iOS4](https://devforums.apple.com/message/254875#254875)

There is no certain solution, but some suggest that a start is changing from arm6 to arm7 and try.

You can try changing some code in the app for producing a different binary and submit it again.

I hope it can help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Check the crash report on itunesconnect.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 3G also supports iOS 4, except it "doesn't support multitasking" (presumably due to lack of RAM?). If you're only seeing crashes on the 3GS and 4, then that might be the issue.

Default.png is shown on launch, but it's also shown on the foreground when the OS didn't manage to get a screenshot while backgrounding, or for various other reasons (e.g. your app was launched with openURL, so the UI is likely to be different).